# Bootstrap -moving horizontal dividers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

my single page bootstrap site has some simple dashed-line horizontal dividers

I've been editing/copy & pasting the code but i cant figure out how to place them where I want.

There is one I **don’t** want on top of the “our mattresses’ section.

id also like to place a divider between the Oisin & Lir mattresses.

http://www.homecollection.ie/darcy/

Answer (score 0):

There is a block, `<div class="divider"></div>` that puts in the dashed lines.

If you remove it where you don't want it, they'll go away.

You can also add it where you want them to be added.

Comment: Thanks. Thats the line of code ive been working with but im missing something becuse its not working..